# Why is $X/B = T^2 \vee S^1$ in the following picture?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Why, in the following picture (from problem 2.1.17 in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*), do we get that $X/B = T^2 \vee S^1$ (according to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95374/relative-homology-groups-of-the-torus))?

The way I imagine it (which I can see must be incorrect) is by holding this double torus around $B$ and squeezing it down to a point. Is it because I can now imagine deformation retracting the RHS to $S^1$ in some odd way? How should I be thinking about these sort of scenarios so I can better identify the familiar spaces that can characterise the resulting space?

[image]

Comment: Once $B$ has been "squeezed down to a point", you can roll back each of the two spikes, along each half of the horizontal circle.

Comment: @AnneBauval thanks - do you mind clarifying what you mean by 'spikes'?

Comment: Sorry, I used GoogleTranslate from french "faire reculer les deux pointes" I meant the 2 kind of cones whose common vertex is the result of squeezing B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the following result quite useful to check things like this (see eg Hatcher's Proposition 0.17, or the special case just before Example 0.7):

> If $A \to X$ is a cofibration (for instance if $(X, A)$ is a good pair, in Hatcher's terminology), and $A$ is contractible then $X \to X/A$ is a homotopy equivalence.

$X/B$ is the same as a torus with two points identified and by above instead of identifying we can just join them with a segment. Now instead of collapsing this segment, collapse a different path joining the two points along the surface of the torus. Then the torus remains a torus but the added segment becomes a circle, wedged to the torus.

Hatcher's Example 0.8 is very similar, with one genus lower, so you start with a torus with a collapsed circle or a sphere with two points identified.